# sql server table data into parent child table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Name   group    subgroup 
--------------------------
A        B          C
A        B          D
A        E          F
A        E          G
H        I          J
H        I          K
H        L          M
H        L          N
```

into

```
ID Name ParentID 
----------------------
1  A    NULL       
2  B    1          
3  C    2          
4  D    2         
5  E    1         
6  F    5         
7  G    5          
8  H    NULL  
9  I   8          
10  J    9          
11  K    9         
12  L    8        
13  M    12         
14  N    12
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried? Give more detailed explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: What rules are you using to determine the parent ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO NEWTAB("Name")
SELECT DISTINCT "Name" 
FROM TAB;

INSERT INTO NEWTAB("Name", "ParentID")
SELECT DISTINCT C."group", P."ID"
FROM TAB C
LEFT JOIN NEWTAB P
  ON C."Name" = P."Name";

INSERT INTO NEWTAB("Name", "ParentID")
SELECT DISTINCT C."subgroup", P."ID"
FROM TAB C
LEFT JOIN NEWTAB P
  ON C."group" = P."Name";
```